# How to add Assembly Manifest file to .exe file created with NetBeans IDE C++ MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, uac

How to add Assembly Manifest file to .exe file created with NetBeans IDE using MinGW, C++? The file looks like (just an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity version="7.0.0.0"
   processorArchitecture="X86"
   name="nbexec.exe"
   type="win32"/>

<description>nbexec Process.</description>
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
    />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="asInvoker"
        uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
     </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

How can I include this information in EXE file?

The problem is that in Windows Vista the file is marked with UAC sign, but it is digitally signed. And I'm asked to confirm to let it execute every time I launch it..

I found such explanation [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/): *"Firstly, you must create an XML manifest specifying that version 6 of the Windows common controls library must be loaded by Windows, and embed it into your application as a resource with type “RT_MANIFEST” (actually, if you prefer you can name the manifest “[application name].exe.manifest” and include it in the same directory as the exe, rather than embedding it as a resource, but that does have the disadvantage that it can become accidentally deleted or corrupted)."*

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself, maybe it will be useful for others too.

Actions:

1. Create header file **ids.h**

> ```
> #ifndef RESOURCE_H
> #define   RESOURCE_H
>
> #ifdef    __cplusplus
> extern "C" {
> #endif
>
> #define IDI_ICON_128  101
>
> #ifdef    __cplusplus
> }
> #endif
>
> #endif    /* RESOURCE_H */
>
> #define CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID 1 /*Defined manifest file*/
> #define RT_MANIFEST                       24
> ```

2. Create resource file **resource.rc** and include **ids.h**

> ```
> #include "ids.h" 
>
> CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "Some.exe.manifest"
>
> IDI_ICON_128 ICON "SomeIcon.ico"
>
> 1 VERSIONINFO
> FILEVERSION     1,0,0,0
> PRODUCTVERSION  1,0,0,0
> BEGIN
>   BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
>   BEGIN
>     BLOCK "080904E4"
>     BEGIN
>       VALUE "CompanyName", "Some company"
>       VALUE "FileDescription", "Some description"
>       VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0"
>       VALUE "InternalName", "Some file name"
>       VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Some copyright"
>       VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Some.exe"
>       VALUE "ProductName", "Some product name"
>       VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0"
>     END
>   END
>
>   BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
>   BEGIN
>     VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1252
>   END
> END
> ```

You can see **"Some.exe.manifest"** assembly manifest file name
This file (XML file, as you can see in my question above) should be in project class path.

Now here are **resource.rc** properties:

[image]

3. In project properties - **Linker** options:

[image]

You can see "Additional Dependencies" - **resource.o**

And that's all - .exe file contains assembly manifest file (also icon and description) after compiling it.

Project view:

[image]

Project files view:

[image]